# Cannot merge previous revisions back to working copy with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN (1.6.11), I **CANNOT** merge a **previous revision back to working copy**.

Steps:

(1) show logs

(2) right click targeted revision

(3) choose merge revision to

(4) select a merge target, click ok

Nothing happens, my woriking copy doesn't contain the change in selected revision.

By the way, if I save the files in that revision (right click the files -> save revision to), the downloaded files still contain no changes done at this revision.

Do I misunderstand the concept of revision or merge?

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure that your working copy is in the same branch (or a copy) that what you are trying to merge. Otherwise, svn will not see any changes since the files are not in the same source tree.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the revision your are trying to merge in does not contain the changes you expect, as otherwise you would see them when you save the file!

In TortoiseSVN, when looking at the log of a file, you can double-click each file committed in that revision to show the changes that were made. When merging a revision, only the changes made in that revision will be merged! You can select a range of revisions if you need more changes.

NB: You say that you are merging a "previous" revision. If it is from the same branch/tag as your working version, then your working version could well already contain that change, explaining why nothing happens.